# Get queue name from inside QueueClient.OnMessage callback

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

[QueueClient.OnMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.onmessage.aspx) takes a callback, `Action<BrokeredMessaged>`, as an argument that will be executed by an internal message pump that's constantly polling a queue (or subscription) when a message is available.

I've been looking at the BrokeredMessage type in Reflector but can't find a way to get the queue name that the message came **from the BrokeredMessage object** (that last part is key). If this is possible, how can it be pulled out?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out a solution using reflection:

```
public void OnMessageCallback(BrokeredMessage message) {
    var context = message.GetType().GetProperty("ReceiveContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(message);
    var receiver = (MessageReceiver)context.GetType().GetProperty("MessageReceiver", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(context);
    var queueName = receiver.Path;
}
```

Comment: Reflection can break if internals of the `MessageReceiver` change. Could you elaborate on what's the need to identify the entity message is coming from? Note that for the events, you'll get the topic, but not the subscription.

Comment: Hi SeanFeldman, thanks for the reply. I can record information on both the sender and consumer sides of the ASB. I want to be able to record enough to tie any message received back to its sender. I think that this will require me to know the endpoint address and the message's SequenceNumber (possibly the InternalId? or CorrelationId? or would MessageId be enough? I'm not sure). 

So for what I want to do, it might be okay to only have access to the topic and not the subscription from the consumer's side.

I welcome any thoughts!

Comment: Recording information would help indeed, as then that info is stored with the message (in the headers). Just like a message that is being forwarded has the info in the headers. I would suggest to look into something like NServiceBus or MassTransit once you get into complexity like this and spend a lot of efforts on boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `QueueClient.OnMessage`, you can do something like that:

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
client.OnMessage(message =>
{

    // You always have access to the queue path
    var queueName = client.Path;
});
```

If you don't want to use anonymous function you can pass the queueName to the function that is going to process you message:

```
public void ProcessMessage(BrokeredMessage message, string queueName)
{

}
```

And call you function like that:

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
client.OnMessage(message =>
{
    ProcessMessage(message , client.Path);
});
```

**EDIT** : Using a [MessageReceiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.aspx)

Azure ServiceBus SDK provides an abstraction to receive messages from queues or subscriptions:

```
var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("MyConnectionString");
var messageReceiver = messagingFactory.CreateMessageReceiver("MyQueueName");
messageReceiver.OnMessage(message =>
{

    // You always have access to the queue path
    var queueName = messageReceiver.Path;
}, new OnMessageOptions());
```

Comment: Won't help when you don't want to distinguish between queues and subscriptions. I.e. when using MessageReceiver.OnMessage this won't work.

Comment: It is simple enough to convert this code to use a MessageReceiver. Message receiver also has a Path property.

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't have access to a QueueClient object from within my callback. This is the main reason I stressed needing to obtain it from the BrokeredMessage parameter (or some static means).